# Merging 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionary:

a=

```
{
    "2001935072": {
        "WR": "48.9",
        "nickname": "rogs30541",
        "team": 2
    },
....
}
```

and

b=

```
{
    "2001935072": {
        "wtr": 816
    },
....
}
```

i've tried to merge them with both a.update(b) and a={**a, **b} but both gives this output when i print(a):

```
{
    "2001935072": {
        "wtr": 816
    },
....
}
```

which is basicly a=b, how to merge A and B so the output is

```
{
    "2001935072": {
        "WR": "48.9",
        "nickname": "rogs30541",
        "team": 2
        "wtr": 816
    },
....
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: What should the rule for conflicting keys be. Meaning, which value should be taken if let's say `a["2001935072"]["WR"]=48.9` and `b["2001935072"]["WR"]=50`?

Comment: @usr2564301 tried that method, same result

Comment: Loop the keys and merge them each, as you hold a dict of dicts, and `update` isn't recursive. Something like `{key: a[key].update(value) for key, value in b.iteritems()}`

Comment: @FlyingTeller there wont be any conflicting keys because b will only contain "wtr" and nothing else

Comment: @casraf i thought about that but asked here because i think theres more simple way to do it :( . Alright then ill do just that thx man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:-**

```
for i,j in a.items():
    for x,y in b.items():
        if i==x:
            j.update(y)

print(a) #your updateed output
```

Comment: that's very bad complexity-wise: useless `O(n**2)`

Answer (score 3):

I would compute the union of the keys, then rebuild the dictionary merging the inner dictionaries together with an helper method (because dict merging is possible in 3.6+ inline but not before) ([How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression))

```
a={
    "2001935072": {
        "WR": "48.9",
        "nickname": "rogs30541",
        "team": 2
    }
    }
b= {
    "2001935072": {
        "wtr": 816
    },

}
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    """Given two dicts, merge them into a new dict as a shallow copy."""
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z

result = {k:merge_two_dicts(a.get(k,{}),b.get(k,{})) for k in set(a)|set(b)}

print(result)
```

result:

```
{'2001935072': {'WR': '48.9', 'nickname': 'rogs30541', 'team': 2, 'wtr': 816}}
```

notes:

- `a.get(k,{})` allows to get the value for `k` with a default of  so merge still works, only retaining values from `b` dict.
- `merge_two_dicts` is just an *helper* function. Not to be used with `a` and `b` dicts directly or it will give the wrong result, since last merged one "wins" and overwrites the other dict values

With Python 3.6+: you can do that without any helper function:

```
result = {k:{**a.get(k,{}),**b.get(k,{})} for k in set(a)|set(b)}
```

Comment: works perfectly on my machine. what is the error? I don't have access to replit.

Comment: when i run merge_two_dicts(a, b) the result is {
    "2001935072": {
        "wtr": 816
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try list + dict comprehension to achieve your results:

```
>>> a = {"2001935072":{"WR":"48.9","nickname":"rogs30541","team":2}}
>>> b = {"2001935072":{"wtr":816}}
>>> l = dict([(k,a.get(k),b.get(k)) for k in set(list(a.keys()) + list(b.keys()))])
```

This will output:

```
>>> [('2001935072', {'WR': '48.9', 'nickname': 'rogs30541', 'team': 2}, {'wtr': 816})]
```

Finally to achieve your desired output

```
>>> dict((k,{**va,**vb}) for k,va,vb in l)
>>> {'2001935072': {'WR': '48.9', 'nickname': 'rogs30541', 'team': 2, 'wtr': 816}}
```